# Javascript array starts with a comma?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was solving this problem on leetcode, and it appears that I found a good solution. The algorithm has to return an array of running sum. For example, if input is nums `[1,2,3,4]` the output must be `[1,3,6,10]`. My algorithm seems to be working fine, however the output starts with a comma and I can't get it done.

Here is my algorithm:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var runningSum = function(nums) {
  let output = new Array(nums.length)
  var sum = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < nums.length + 1; i++) {
    sum = sum + nums[i - 1];
    output[i] = sum;
  }
  return output;
};
```

When given `[1,2,3,4]` it returns `[,1,3,6,10]` and I can't understand why there is a comma at the beginning of the output array and how to make it right.

Comment: Array indices in JavaScript are _zero-based_.

Comment: What jonrsharpe said. The variable i needs to run from 0 to nums.length - 1.
This code skips the first position in the array, which is [0].
Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

If you inspect your code closely, you will see that you never actually assign to `output[0]`. That is because your loop starts from `i=1` and you assign to `output[i]`.

There is no need for the loop to start from 1 - you access the element `i` of the input array, add it to `sum`, and assign that to the element `i` of the output array. Just change the loop to:

```
for (let i=0 ; i<nums.length ; i++){
    sum = sum + nums[i];
    output[i] = sum;
}
```